# IPhone: How to call AlertView from a Static Function

Tags: iphone

I have a class as follows

```
#import "UtilAlert.h"

@implementation UtilAlert

+(void) showAlert:(NSString *)message andTitle:(NSString *)title andDelegate:(UIViewController *) delegate
{
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:title message:message delegate:delegate cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alert show];

}

@end
```

The problem is that when call the function with  necessary parameters...

```
[UtilAlert showAlert:@"hello" andTitle:@"hello" andDelegate:self] ;
```

i get a error: **Thread 1: stopped at  break point 3;**

for the function call from an UIController class

Comment: Can you post your .h file as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not an error. You have a breakpoint in your code, which is the little blue arrow in the left margin of your code. Click the blue arrow again to make it really light blue to turn off the breakpoint.

Also, you should release the alert after showing it before exiting the function or you will leak memory.

Answer (score 0):

Just a wild guess, but your `alert` object may be released when the function exits if your are working on ARC. In that case, this might work :

```
+(void) showAlert:(NSString *)message andTitle:(NSString *)title andDelegate:(UIViewController *) delegate { 
    static UIAlertView *alert;
    if(!alert)
        alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:title message:message delegate:delegate cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles:nil]; 

    [alert show];
}
```

Comment: how would you then create a buttonIndex inside a static function?